# How can I create a closure table using data from an adjacency list?

Tags: sql, sql-server, hierarchy, transitive-closure-table

I have a database containing a hierarchy of categories stored using the adjacency list model.

The hierarchy is 3 levels deep (not including an imaginary root node) and contains approx 1700 nodes. Nodes in the 2nd and 3rd levels can have multiple parents. A additional table is used for the many-to-many relationship as below:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Category(
    id int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
)

CREATE TABLE dbo.CategoryHierarchy(
    relId int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    catId int NOT NULL,
    parentId int NOT NULL,
)
```

If I move to using the transitive closure table method (for the sake of data integrity etc) is there a relatively easy query I can execute that would generate the values for the closure table? (using SQL Server 2005)

I've look through articles and presentations such as Bill Karwin's [Models for hierarchical data](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/models-for-hierarchical-data) but that only has insertion queries for a single node and it would take forever for me to create my tree like that.

Thanks.

**EDIT:** 
RelID in the CategoryHierarchy table is purely for the sake of a primary key, it has no bearing on the node ids of the Category table.

Also by closure table, I mean a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE ClosureTable (
    ancestor int NOT NULL,
    descendant int NOT NULL,
    [length] int NOT NULL,
)
```

Where the first two columns are a compound primary key, and are individually foreign keys to Category.id.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think I've been able to work out the solution myself.

If anyone has a better way of doing this, please comment.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.ClosureTable', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE dbo.ClosureTable
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.ClosureTable (
    ancestor int NOT NULL,
    descendant int NOT NULL,
    distance int NULL
)
GO

DECLARE @depth INT
SET @depth = 1

INSERT INTO dbo.ClosureTable (ancestor, descendant, distance)
SELECT catid, catid, 0 FROM dbo.Category -- insert all the self-referencing nodes

WHILE (@depth < 4) -- my tree is only 4 levels deep, i.e 0 - 3
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.ClosureTable (ancestor, descendant, distance)
    SELECT ct.ancestor, h.catid, @depth
    FROM dbo.ClosureTable ct INNER JOIN dbo.CategoryHierarchy h ON ct.descendant = h.parentid
    WHERE ct.distance = @depth - 1

    SET @depth = @depth + 1
END
```

Cheers :)

Answer (score 20):

I was trying to figure out the same thing, but wanted it in a recursive CTE. This wouldn't have worked for you (SQL Server 2008+), but here's what I ended up with for anyone else looking.

The key is that the anchors aren't your root nodes (where `parent_id IS NULL`), but instead *all* your zero depth rows-to-be in the closure table.

#### Table

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.category (
    id         INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
    parent_id  INT                    NULL
)
```

#### Data

```
INSERT INTO dbo.category (id, parent_id)
VALUES
    (1, NULL),
    (2, 1),
    (3, 1),
    (4, 2)
```

#### CTE

```
WITH category_cte AS
(
    SELECT
        id AS ancestor,
        id AS descendant,
        0  AS depth
    FROM dbo.category

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        CTE.ancestor  AS ancestor,
        C.id          AS descendant,
        CTE.depth + 1 AS depth
    FROM dbo.category AS C
    JOIN category_cte AS CTE
        ON C.parent_id = CTE.descendant
)
SELECT * FROM category_cte
```

#### Result

```
ancestor descendant depth
-------- ---------- -----
1        1          0     <- anchor query
2        2          0
3        3          0
4        4          0
2        4          1     <- first recursive query
1        2          1
1        3          1
1        4          2     <- second recursive query
```

Answer (score 3):

```
  WITH Children (id, name, iteration) AS (
    SELECT id, name, 0
    FROM Category 
    --WHERE id = @folderid -- if you want a startpoint
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT b.id, b.name, a.iteration + 1
    FROM Children AS a, Category AS b, CategoryHierarchy c
    WHERE a.id = c.parentId
      AND b.id = c.catId 
  )
  SELECT id, name, iteration FROM Children
```

Not tested, but should work like this. At least a start how you do this fast without loops.

EDIT: I missred, not relId, it is parentId that has to link to Childrens table. But the result should be a table with all tables. So this is not what your originally wanted?

Comment: Thanks @YvesR, however that doesn't really help. The closure table would only have the columns: ancestor, descendant, depth.  Also RelId is just an additional column for the sake of a primary key - it has no bearing on the node ids. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: Edited my post. I thought you wanted a table result with all rows and its relations? If you need more informations you can join them after as well.