# Recursive search in database table including from one to N parents for each row

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the table, which looks like that

```
 id   parent_id
 1    null
 2    1
 3    2
 4    1
 5    3
```

For each row in the table I want to retrieve information about its parents(from first to N generation). It means, if row with `id = 3` has `parent_id = 2` and `id = 2` has `parent_id = 1`, then `3` belongs to `2` and `1` as well.

The **result** I want to get:

```
id    multi_level_parent_id
 1    null
 2    1
 3    2
 3    1
 4    1
 5    3
 5    2
 5    1
```

I assume, that I have to use recursive `select`. I has written SQL code, but it returns information only about first generation

```
WITH Rec AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM MyTable t
    UNION ALL
    SELECT *
    FROM MyTable t
    INNER JOIN Rec r ON t.id = r.parent_id
)

SELECT *
FROM Rec
```

Does anybody know how to retrieve information, what I need?

Comment: You are describing a closure table...  Try here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12621873/how-can-i-create-a-closure-table-using-data-from-an-adjacency-list  You may need to make some slight modifications to get your exact result set

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what you are after:

```
WITH Rec
     AS (
     SELECT id,
            id AS parent_id,
            0 AS steps
     FROM MyTable  t
     UNION ALL
     SELECT r.id,
            t.parent_id,
            r.steps + 1 AS steps
     FROM MyTable  t
          INNER JOIN Rec r ON t.id = r.parent_id)
     SELECT id,
            parent_id
     FROM MyTable 
     WHERE parent_id IS NULL
     UNION ALL
     SELECT id,
            parent_id
     FROM Rec
     WHERE parent_id <> id
     ORDER BY id;
```

and the results:

[image]