Employee hierarchy
I'm trying to produce a result that will show a row for each level of management per associate.
I can do a recursive cte to figure out the level a person is at, but what I want to see is a result set that shows the person repeated for each level in their structure.
For example, a level 5 associate, should show 5 rows and each row would have the associate name repeated, with the manager and current level for that row.
I'm using the [dbo].[DimEmployee] table from AdventureWorksDW2014 for my sample data.
Here is what I want to see in my result set
enter image description here
Here is the recursive CTE that shows the level, but what other query can I use to get the multiple rows per level like my sample above.
WITH RCTE AS
(
    SELECT
        E.EmployeeKey,
        E.FirstName + ' ' + E.LastName AS Name,
        E.ParentEmployeeKey,
        1 AS Level
    FROM  
        [dbo].[DimEmployee] AS E
    WHERE
        E.ParentEmployeeKey IS NULL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        E.EmployeeKey,
        E.FirstName + ' ' + E.LastName AS Name,
        E.ParentEmployeeKey,
        RCTE.Level + 1 AS Level
    FROM 
        [dbo].[DimEmployee] AS E
    JOIN 
        RCTE ON E.ParentEmployeeKey = RCTE.EmployeeKey
)
SELECT 
    RCTE.*
FROM 
    RCTE
WHERE 
    RCTE.EmployeeKey = 265
ORDER BY 
    RCTE.Level, RCTE.ParentEmployeeKey, RCTE.EmployeeKey

enter image description here

Build a closure table for your hierarchy (what is a closure table?). You can use a recursive CTE to build it just like you have used in your question, but it gets built the other way around - instead of using the root node as the anchor set for the CTE, the anchor set is every node. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12621873/how-can-i-create-a-closure-table-using-data-from-an-adjacency-list

There are two ways that I can think of. Which one you use is informed by use case.
Resolving one employee only
There's nothing saying that you have to traverse the hierarchy from root (i.e. CEO in an org tree) to leaf (i.e. associate in an org tree). If you're only trying to get the reporting structure for one employee, you can start at that employee and move towards the root.
WITH RCTE AS
(
    SELECT
        E.EmployeeKey,
        E.FirstName + ' ' + E.LastName AS Name,
        E.ParentEmployeeKey,
        1 AS Level
    FROM  
        [dbo].[DimEmployee] AS E
    WHERE
        E.EmployeeKey = 265


    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        parent.EmployeeKey,
        parent.FirstName + ' ' + parent.LastName AS Name,
        parent.ParentEmployeeKey,
        child.Level + 1 AS Level
    FROM 
        [dbo].[DimEmployee] AS parent
    JOIN 
        RCTE as child ON child.ParentEmployeeKey = parent.EmployeeKey
)
select *
from RCTE
order by level desc

NB - the levels are the opposite of what they are in root-to-leaf traversal. If you need the CEO to be level 1 and the leaf level employee to be the highest, you'll have to do some math.
Resolving multiple employees
If you want to pass in multiple employees to the query, it gets a little trickier (but not terribly so). I'm going to use hierarchyid (which is SQL Server specific but is a general implementation of a materialized path pattern). The idea here is that we're going to go back to root-to-leaf traversal but build up a path to each node in the tree as we go. We can then use that path for a given employee as a way to get back to the root.
WITH RCTE AS
(
    SELECT
        E.EmployeeKey,
        E.FirstName + ' ' + E.LastName AS Name,
        E.ParentEmployeeKey,
        1 AS Level,
        cast(concat('/', E.EmployeeKey, '/') as varchar(1000)) as h
    FROM  
        [dbo].[DimEmployee] AS E
    WHERE
        E.ParentEmployeeKey IS NULL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        E.EmployeeKey,
        E.FirstName + ' ' + E.LastName AS Name,
        E.ParentEmployeeKey,
        RCTE.Level + 1 AS Level,
        cast(concat(RCTE.h, e.EmployeeKey, '/') as varchar(1000))
    FROM 
        [dbo].[DimEmployee] AS E
    JOIN 
        RCTE ON E.ParentEmployeeKey = RCTE.EmployeeKey
)
SELECT 
    parent.*
FROM 
    RCTE as parent
JOIN
    RCTE as child
ON
    cast(child.h as hierarchyid).IsDescendantOf(cast(parent.h as hierarchyid)) = 1
WHERE 
    child.EmployeeKey = 265
ORDER BY 
    child.Level, child.ParentEmployeeKey, child.EmployeeKey;

Now, I will say that dynamically calculating the hierarchyid on every query is sub-optimal. If you wanted to do this "for real", I'd encourage you to materialize that as a column in the table. At which point you can index it. You do incur the carrying cost of maintaining it when the reporting structure changes, but that's a trade-off.

Thanks, this is perfect and exactly what I was looking for, I added one thing, which was child.EmployeeKey, as I need their ID repeated.  I didn't think of going backwards through the tree and didn't know about the IsDescendantOf in SQL Server, so this is good to know.  Appreciate the solution, now time to see how I can make this work with real data.
